# ARKit2 Video Asset Streaming

Tags: augmented-reality, arkit

I am building an app in `Arkit2` that will render video over 2d photos. The HD videos (.MP4 files) I have are about above 25 MB. I have about 50 of them in the app.

To reduce the app size I am streaming the app videos from our web server. But this is making my Bandwidth go through the roof. And if I had hundreds of users streaming the videos, our hosting bill would be ridiculous.

Is there a way we can stream from Youtube or other similar services instead? I have tried to do this unsuccessfully in `Arkit2`

I'd really appreciate feedback and suggestions on this.

Comment: How about ODR? (on demand resources)

Comment: can you elaborate on this more? I need a direct link, I tried a lot, it does not work, you can connect plugins, but it will take time

Comment: With ODR, you package content with the app but it will be downloaded only upon request and deleted if free space is needed. It is typically used for games that require 
 a lot of resources. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/On_Demand_Resources_Guide/ and https://github.com/maxvol/RxOnDemandResources

Comment: Can we grab a beer and chat about this? I would love to hear how I can use your ODR to solve this AR asset problem in Arkit2